# Assert that one JSON, which is like a list of maps, contains another JSON

Tags: java, json

I have a test that is trying to assert if the acutal json object, from the rest API call, contains the expected JSON, that I hard coded.
My actual JSON that looks like

```
{
    "data": [{
        "requiredness": "required",
        "multi_value": false,
        "editable": true,
        "name": "name__v",
        "type": "String",
        "max_length": 50
    }, {
        "requiredness": "required",
        "multi_value": false,
        "editable": true,
        "name": "label__v",
        "type": "String",
        "max_length": 100
    }, {
        "requiredness": "required",
        "multi_value": false,
        "editable": true,
        "name": "active__v",
        "type": "Boolean"
    }, {
        "requiredness": "required",
        "component": "Doctype",
        "multi_value": false,
        "editable": true,
        "name": "type__v",
        "type": "Component"
    }, {
        "requiredness": "conditional",
        "component": "Doctype",
        "multi_value": false,
        "editable": true,
        "name": "subtype__v",
        "type": "Component"
    }, {
        "requiredness": "optional",
        "component": "Doctype",
        "multi_value": false,
        "editable": true,
        "name": "classification__v",
        "type": "Component"
    }, {
        "requiredness": "optional",
        "multi_value": false,
        "editable": true,
        "name": "filing_model__v",
        "type": "Object"
    }],
    "responseStatus": "SUCCESS"
}
```

And I want to assert that the following expected JSON contains only one map, from the list of the maps:

```
{  
   "data":[  
      {  
         "requiredness":"required",
         "multi_value":false,
         "editable":true,
         "name":"name__v",
         "type":"String",
         "max_length":50
      }
   ],
   "responseStatus":"SUCCESS"
}
```

This is my test

```
public void test(){
    JSONObject actualjson = callAPI(endpoint);
    JSONObject expectedjson =new JSONObject(expectedOutput);
    Assert.assertThat(actualjson.toString(),CoreMatchers.containsString(ExpectedjsonObj.toString()));
   }
```

I get an exception due to the white spaces:

```
Expected: a string containing "{\"data\":[{\"requiredness\":\"required\",\"multi_value\":false,\"editable\":true,\"name\":\"name__v\",\"type\":\"String\",\"max_length\":50}],\"responseStatus\":\"SUCCESS\"}"
```

but what was obtained was

```
"{"data":[{"requiredness":"required","multi_value":false,"editable":true,"name":"name__v","type":"String","max_length":50},{"requiredness":"required","multi_value":false,
```

What is the best approach to assert that the list of maps in my actual JSON contains my expected maps( could be a list too)

Comment: What is the method you are testing actually intended to do?  Is the purpose of the method to write JSON?  Or is the purpose of the method to manipulate the objects that the JSON being written represents?  Or does the method do a bit of both?  Adding tested method and the test case would be helpful.

Comment: try json assert for checking, might help

Comment: Ordering of JSON keys is not guaranteed. You can't just string compare them.

Comment: Since you speak in terms of JSONObject, I have the following questions: are you implementing a JSON writer?  Or is "writing JSON" a small feature for a larger app in which JSONObject actually being used as a representation of another piece of data?  What is the tested code actually doing?  Is there a particular reason why you are not leaving the nitty gritty of JSON writing to proven frameworks such as [Jackson](http://wiki.fasterxml.com/JacksonHome)?  In any case, I would suggest not using string comparisons, but comparing elements in your data model instead.

Comment: Thank you @BrandonMcKenzie, the test code is trying to call the API and capture the actual JSON. As my API response contains a long list of metadata, i do not want to assert the existence of every element in my test. for example, if I want to make sure that the element with "name": "name__v", and the element with "name": "subtype__v", exists in my actual json, How do I add such an assertion to the test.

Answer (score 1):

Since you're testing the output of a REST API call, and order is not necessarily guaranteed in your output, the solution is exactly the thing you expressed that you did not want to do: assert the existence of every element in the JSONObject.  Fortunately, the [JSONAssert](https://github.com/skyscreamer/JSONassert) library may be utilized to do that for you.